# nodejs request locks up for no apparent reason

Tags: node.js, request, timeout

I am developing and testing an application that uses a search bar to lookup database records.

I've run into a strange problem where I can execute several searches all of which return results properly and then my app will lock up for no apparent reason and take about 120 seconds for the request to timeout before I can do anything else. I log every request and there doesn't seem to be any apparent reason for the lock-up other than it seems like it's some sort of timeout. I can type the exact same query string that it locked up on and it will execute properly but after several searches it will lock up again.

I have error handlers that log to the console and no errors are reported, in fact it will return a 200 response header after it times out. This last time I tested it said the request took 36ms but I know by looking at the clock 120 seconds had elapsed. Is there any way to diagnose what may be causing the issue? When it locks up any new requests will also be frozen until the request timesout.

I am unable to post any code snippets right now as parts of it are sensitive but I can post the list of dependencies which I suspect may be one of the issues:

```
"bcrypt-nodejs": "latest",
"body-parser": "~1.0.0",
"connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
"cookie-parser": "~1.0.0",
"ejs": "latest",
"express": "~4.0.0",
"express-mysql-session": "^1.2.0",
"connect-mongo" : "latest",
"express-session": "~1.0.0",
"method-override": "~1.0.0",
"morgan": "~1.0.0",
"mssql": "latest",
"mysql": "latest",
"mongoose" : "latest",
"passport": "~0.1.17",
"passport-local": "~0.1.6",
"request": "^2.79.0",
"request-promise": "^4.1.1",
"socket.io": "latest"
```

I am running Node v6.9.2 in a Windows 8.1 environment. The requests are sent via POST to a route handler, which queries a mssql database and returns a formatted JSON reply to the client. 
If any other information is needed please let me know.
Thanks,
-Tim

```html
----------------------------SERVER.JS-----------------------------------
const port      = 3002
var express     = require('express')
var app         = express()                           
var server      = require('http').Server(app)
var io          = require('socket.io')(server)
cookieParser   = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser')
// SESSION
session       = require('express-session')
MongoStore    = require('connect-mongo')(session)
var passport  = require('passport')
var flash     = require('connect-flash')

// DEV
var morgan    = require('morgan')

// DATABASE
configDB = require('./config/database.js')
mongoose    = require('mongoose')
mssql       = require('mssql')
mysql       = require('mysql')

// CONFIG
require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(morgan('dev')); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.use(cookieParser()); 
app.use(bodyParser()); 
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
const mongoConnect = mongoose.createConnection(configDB.mongoConnectString)
app.use(session({
  secret: '*******',
  store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoConnect})
}))  
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); 
app.use(flash()); 
// CACHE CONTROL
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) { res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate') }
    next()
})
// ROUTES
require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport);
//ERROR HANDLER
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.log("ErrorHandler: " + err.stack)
})
//Start Server
server.listen(port);
console.log('App launched on port '  + port);


--------------------------------- Routes.js ----------------------------------------------
module.exports = function(app, passport){                                                          
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if(req.user){
    return res.redirect('/profile')
  }
  else {
    res.render('home.ejs', {dest_page: req.query.dest_page, html_content: '<h2>Welcome! Please Login</h2>', main_content: 'login',  loggedState: 'Login', loginError: req.flash('loginMessage') })    
  }
 })
 app.post('/lookup', isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var lookup = require('../app/models/lookup')
  switch(req.query.command) {           
    case "search_results" : 
   finishRequest = function(err, records){ res.render('client_lookup', { errorMessage: err, client: records, user : req.user}) }
   lookup.client(req.body.s)
   break
    default :
   res.render('home.ejs', {errorMessage: 'Error: nothing to show', user : req.user})
   break
  }
   }) 
   }
  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated())
      return next()
    res.redirect('/?dest_page=' + req.url)
  }
  ------------------------------- Lookup.js -------------------------------------------
function Lookup() {}
Lookup.client = function(s){
    var query
 if(typeof s == 'undefined'){
      finishRequest("Search string not set", null)
    }
    s = s.trim()
    if(s.length <= 2){
      finishRequest("At least 2 characters required", null) 
    }
    // Match Date
 if(s.match(/^\d\d[-.\/]\d\d[-.\/](\d\d|\d\d\d\d)/)){
  query = '(date match query)'
 }
 // Match Phone
 else if (s.match(/^[()0-9]+/)){
  query = '(phone match query)'
 }
 // Match Name
 else if(s.match(/^[a-z]/)){
  query = '(name match query)'
 }
 else {
  finishRequest('Unrecognized Pattern!', null)
 }
 mssql.connect(configDB.mssql).then(function(){
  new mssql.Request().query(query).then(function(records){
    if(records.length > 0)
   finishRequest(null, records)
    else 
   finishRequest("Nothing Found!", null)
  }).catch(function(err){
   finishRequest(err, null)
  })
 })                     
}
module.exports = Lookup
```

Comment: But where is the code? Show the code, especially stuff where you handle request that caused problem.

Comment: Most code alone isn't sensitive, just the credentials and keys inside them.  If you need non-trivial help, you will need to post some amount of code, just not all of it.  As a random guess, I would look at MySQL, you may have a callback that isn't called until the database forces the connection closed, instead of once the data has finished being returned.

Comment: I've updated to include some code snippets that should be relevant to the issue, hope that helps. Thanks!